# Rebuild RAID with Old HDD in Synology NAS

Tags: raid, raid-1, synology, synology-diskstation

A HDD has been removed from a two bay Synology NAS (DS214j). The remaining HDD is working fine as remaining part of the degraded RAID 1.

Is it possible to re-add the once removed HDD in the NAS to fix the downgraded RAID 1, like it would with a brand new drive?

Or may this be a problem, because the host remembers the HDD (e.g. by the S/N) and cannot decide which drive is up to date?

Comment: I notice you haven't got an answer to this yet - have you tried contacting Synology support?

Comment: No I will not contact them. I will take the safe path, backing up everything, then try to recreate RAID 1 and posting the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all partitions via the Windows Partition Manager from the once removed HDD and put it into the shutdown NAS.

I then started the RAID repair in the Synology storage manager and the RAID has been rebuilt successfully.

Conclusion: Adding a once removed drive into a Synology NAS with DSM worked for me, at least after removing all partitions before inserting the drive.